# How to read a variable before perform <c:choose> operation in JSP?

Tags: java, image, jsp, jstl

I can read my variable using getRating() method. When I print it using

```
<c:out value="${obj.getRating()}" />
```

it prints the value. But what I need is to display an image according to the rating as below.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{obj.getRating() eq 5 }"><img src="images/5star.png" /></c:when>
    <c:when test="#{obj.getRating() eq 4 }"><img src="images/4star.png" /></c:when>
    <c:when test="#{obj.getRating() eq 3 }"><img src="images/3star.png" /></c:when>
    <c:when test="#{obj.getRating() eq 2 }"><img src="images/2star.png" /></c:when>
    <c:otherwise> <img src="images/1star.png" /></c:otherwise>

 </c:choose>
```

Then It gives syntax error. How can I do that? Do I need to read the variable and store in somewhere before go to  ? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
<c:when test="${obj.getRating() eq 5 }">
```

instead of

```
<c:when test="#{obj.getRating() eq 5 }">
```

### use `$` instead of `#`